# Using a variable in $elemMatch

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a user model which contains the array 'ratings', this array contains several objects. Now I want to search if a certain object is in this array using the $elemMatch function from mongoose. If I do it the hard-coded way everything works fine:

```
User.find(
        {
            ratings: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    1: {$gt: 0}
                }
            }
        },
```

However, if I want to use a variable to search, I do not get anything back. I also could not get it working using the var query = {}; method.

```
var variable = 00001;
console.log(variable);
var query = {};
query[variable] = 7;
User.find(
{
    ratings: {
        $elemMatch: {
            variable: {$gt: 0}
        }
    }
},
```

Changing variable into query after the $elemMatch operator does not work either.

Comment: In your second example, what do you expect the full query to look like? It's not clear since you have both `00001` and `7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your query object outside your `find` like you were trying to do. You can create your entire filter outside your find() like I did in option 1 or you can just create a piece and add it to the rest of your filter (option 2).

```
// Option 1
var query = {
    ratings: {
        $elemMatch: {}
    }
};
query.ratings.$elemMatch['1'] = {$gt: 0};

User.find(query)
    .exec(...);

// Option 2
var query = {};
query['1'] = {$gt: 0};

User.find(
{
    ratings: {
        $elemMatch: query
    }
}
)
.exec(...);
```